# repeating cutdown timer after break

Tags: java, android

Hi I would like to repeat this timer (code below) for example 3 times in such a way that the repeated time shows up on tv2. I would also like to repeatability to be after a 10 second break. I really don't know how to do this .

```
  CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv2.setText("Przygotuj się:\n " + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));



        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

     }.start();
```

Comment: save the 'millisUntilFinished ' into a variable and start repeatation with 'countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(saveMillis, 1000)'

Comment: But how to reapeat it?

Comment: as I wrote. `countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(saveMillis, 1000)`